# SQL LIMIT for multiple queries

Tags: php, sql

I have my paging script that gets the page variable and puts in in LIMIT values inside a sql query.

```
LIMIT $page, $limit2
```

it all works well,the problem is that i have 2 sql queries so *LIMIT 0,10* displays 10 results from first query and then 10 more from second query =20 results per page,what i need is to display 10 from 1st QRY and on 2nd page the rest from first QRY and only then to print the results from 2nd query.

I tried *if* statement before whole query an a ++increment inside while loop to even the numbers with found results and then run 2nd QRY but it seems that it doesn't work that way.

also tried something like this with few matematical operations but it also doesn't do much good.

```
    if($page==$printf2)
    {$limit2=10;} 
    if($page==0)
    {$limit2=0;}
```

What would be the proper way of making the 2nd QRY list after 1st one ended,without more than 10 results per page?

Comment: could you please post also the queries? maybe it is possible to merge them and then use just one limit clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "QUERY1 LIMIT $page, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($result);

/* process the result here! */

if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 10) {
    $sql2 = "QUERY2 LIMIT $page, $limit2";
    $result = mysql_query($result);

    /* process result of query 2 */
}
```

This way, the query two is executed only when the rows returned from query1 is the last set of rows in the table.

Comment: It looked good but it acts same as other if statements i tried,on page 2 number of rows is  always same since the query dosent change...so it prints only 1st Qry.

Comment: @Arremer: Not really. The `mysql_num_rows()` would be less than 10 only on the last page. Only then, the second query will be executed and you can list the results from the second query. So until all the rows are returned from the first query, the second query is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

did you evaluate to use UNION statement?

```
SELECT * FROM xxxxx (first query) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM YYYYYY (second query)
```

Comment: union would save me a lot of trouble,im trying it for some time already,problem is that queries are a bit larger than basic example.I had to run few queries just to get enough data for query 1.